# Using push_back() on a vector<vector<char>>

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

So I have a class Board header as followed:

```
class Board
    {
        std::vector<std::vector<char>> _board;
        uint _rows;
        uint _cols;

    public:
        Board();
}
```

And I have this default constructor:

```
    Board::Board()
    {
        _rows = 0;
        _cols = 0;
        _board.push_back(vector<char>(1, '_'));
    }
```

And I just don't understand the syntax of this line of code:

```
 _board.push_back(vector<char>(1, '_'));
```

I mean, it does it's job: it adds a '_' at the end of the first row as it should. But from what I've read about the method push_back() I don't understand why it's not just

```
_board.push_back('_');
```

PS: push_back() signature is:

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

EDIT: The message error I get when using *board.push_back('*'); is:

error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'

Comment: `_board` is a vector of vectors, so the things you push to it have to be vectors.  `'_'` is a char, not a vector.

Comment: So the vector<char> inside is a casting ?  And why is this "1" important ? when I use _board.push_back(vector<char>('_') it's not the same, why ?

Comment: It's not a cast, it's a constructor.  `vector<char>(1, '_')` constructs a `vector<char>` of size 1 whose single element is initialized to `'_'`.  If you replace 1 by 7 you will get a vector of size 7 instead, all of whose elements are initialized to `'_'`.  But `std::vector` doesn't have a constructor that just takes one value and assumes the size to be 1; the designers apparently didn't think that would be useful.

Comment: Ok it's a constructor then ! So my misunderstanding was about vector<char> and not about push_back(). Thanks !

Comment: You can also use curly braces, ***i.e.*** direct-brace-initialization, to construct the inner vector `_board.push_back({'_'});`

Comment: Good to know, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The value type of `_board` is `std::vector<char>`, not `char`.

The value type of `_board.front()` is `char`.

```
    _rows = 0;
    _cols = 0;
    _board.push_back(vector<char>(1, '_'));
```

that doesn't make much sense.  A 0x0 board doesn't have a `_` in it.

Comment: It's a board where all empty spaces are filled with ```_``` so I guess it makes sense

Comment: @jewgah A 0x0 board has 0 spaces, not 1.